# Other ways of doing the incremental load(as unable to proceed with CDC)

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, cdc

I am a little bit new to data warehouse development. I am aware of the CDC for incremental loading but the SQL Server version which we are using doesn't allow us to enable CDC.

I have heard about the triggers but not sure though. Could anyone suggest me some other way of doing the incremental load if not CDC?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql Server v17.1. But it is a standard edition and I believe for CDC we require a Developer or Enterprise edition if am not wrong.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think 17.1 is the version of your SSMS. Try running the query `SELECT @@VERSION;` and see what that brings back.

Comment: Oh yeah.It gave Microsoft SQL Server 2016(RTM)

Answer (score 1):

If your installation of SQL Server 2016 has had SP1 applied, then change data capture is available to you.

[Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017#DW)

The range of other strategies available is probably too broad a topic for this forum, which is why your question hasn't attracted much attention. Leveraging CDC for incrementals, though, is sort of the gold standard, so since you have it, you should run with that.

If you run into specific issues during your development, feel free to come back and ask for assistance.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that my answer to the following question [Incremental loading types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157952/how-to-schedule-an-ssas-cube-refresh-only-for-new-facts-or-updated-dimensions/51241913?noredirect=1), will help you too.